# Locating a text field element using xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i want to locate a text field element using xpath, my code used to look like this, and it worked :

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[(@id='login') or (@name = 'login')]"));
```

But i wanted to make sure that the driver picks a text field, so i changed it to this :

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[((@id='login') or (@name = 'login')) and (@type='text']"));
```

It didn't work, i searched for a solution but i found little to no information on using both OR & AND on xpath.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below worked for me:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[(@id='login' or @name='login') and @type='text']")
```

Comment: i think i just needed to know how to lock the parenthesis haha, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a typo on the last @type- it should have been @type= and also there is a missing `)` from the same @type condition.
Below is the corrected code which I have tested.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[((@id=\"login\") or (@name = \"login\")) and (@type=\"text\")]"));
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, i just want to make sure that the typo was made while editing the question, in my code, i have "@type=".

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[(contains(@id,'login') or contains(@name,'login')) and contains(@type,'text')]";
```